# PrimeNG p-table Editable Column Event Callback not working

Tags: angular, events, edit, primeng

I'm setting up a table with users details.

I'm using Angular and PrimeNG.

How can i get an event back when the row is edited and return the new data edited or a flag?

There is another way to notify that the row is modified?

Using this table: https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table/edit

Example:

Before Edit ->

```
{"name":"Mario","surname":"Rossi","mail":"mariorossi@live.it", "phone":"003900000"}
```

After Edit ->

```
{"name":"Mario","surname":"Rossi","mail":"mariorossi@virgilio.it", "phone":"003900000", "flag":"edit"}
```

Thanks in advance :)

i've already put these callbacks but they are not working

```html
(onEdit)="onEdit($event)" (onEditComplete)="onEditComplete($event)"
```

```html
<p-table [value]="users" >
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
        <tr>
            <th>Nome</th>
            <th>Cognome</th>
            <th>Email</th>
            <th>Cellulare</th>
            <th>Delete</th>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-user>
        <tr>
            <td pEditableColumn styleClass="col-button">


                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.name">
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{user.name}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.surname" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{user.surname}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.mail" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{user.mail}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td pEditableColumn>
                <p-cellEditor>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="input">
                        <input pInputText type="text" [(ngModel)]="user.phone" required>
                    </ng-template>
                    <ng-template pTemplate="output">
                        {{user.phone}}
                    </ng-template>
                </p-cellEditor>
            </td>
            <td><button text="Elimina Utente" type="button" pButton (click)="removeUser(user)" icon="pi pi-times" class="ui-button-danger" title="Elimina Utente"></button>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </ng-template>
</p-table>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the *Cell Editing* section in the [documentation](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/table):

> If you require the edited row data or the selected field in the *onEditInit*, *onEditComplete*, and *onEditCancel* events, bind the row data to the pEditableColumn directive and the field to the pEditableColumnField directive.

```
<td [pEditableColumn]="rowData" [pEditableColumnField]="'year'">
```